# What happens when you cannot join because of family reasons?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, career-switch

One my friend got a job offer from Germany which he accepted. He is married and hence decided to go with his wife, he went to office on the first day but unfortunately his wife became ill and he had to come back to his home country immediately. He told the employer about the incident and since the joining formalities were not complete the employer decided to postpone the joining date.

Now, the problem is his wife couldn't adjust to Berlin due to its culture and food or language since they are english speaker and she has decided to not to move there. Now, he is stuck as he has told the employer that he is coming in next 15days.

The employer has invested a considerable amount of time and money and same with him as he was idle for 3 months as he was waiting for visa process.

How should he convince employer that he cannot join without being harsh or looking stupid?

**Update:**

I had a chat with him yesterday and he told me that his wife is in a serious condition she will be operated next week. He left his job three months back waiting for visa formalities to be completed. I completely sympathise with him because it was none of his fault in fact he went to office first day, if it was his own country then he could have managed things differently. I really feel shame for some people who are commenting like he should leave his wife and all.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere most employers expect professionals to sort out family issues such as moving to a new country out themselves, before committing and accruing big expenses for the employer. Sickness is ok, deciding they don't like a country, culture and food after one day is very different.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere As an employer who brings people from OS sometimes at considerable expense and effort, I'd call it a lot of things, none of them printable in polite company, and some of them quite exotic. :-)

Comment: Did she actually go to Germany?  Even if she has, it doesn't sound like she could have been there for long.

Comment: "culture and food or language since they are english speaker" that sounds unconvincing. The vast majority of (young) Berliners speak English, there are a lot of expats from the whole world, so mentioning this to your employer could sound like a lame excuse.

Comment: @Kilisi so, if anything happens in future then employer would take complete responsibility for that? in my opinion nothing is bigger than human life and nothing was pre planned, I listened his story and convinced myself that it could happen to anyone at anytime.

Comment: @john doe: A co-worker of mine, who moved with his wife from China to Hamburg, spend a three weeks vacation with his wife in Hamburg before signing a contract with us. It was fine for us to wait until he checked with his family if moving was an option. Had he just signed with us and then bailed the contract, I don´t think he could have done anything to save his reputation with us!

Comment: @Daniel well I would say that he was lucky and you were understanding, in his case he had to sign a contract before actually coming hence I don't think he had that luxury.

Comment: @FooBar I think it depends on person to person and we can't generalise it.

Comment: @Kilisi regarding expenses afaik he had to spent a lot of money too he stayed in hotel for around 4 days and had to book returning flight back home that too in emergency. I understand its a loss from both parties so shouldn't be seen one sided.

Comment: @john doe: who was forcing him to sign before he came to Germany?  Said colleague of mine did it of his own account and on his own expenses, All he asked from us was some time to consider.

Comment: @Daniel the HR told him to sign a soft copy of the contract within a limited time frame.

Comment: If I was your friend, I'd find a new wife.

Comment: @johndoe - No, we can generalize it, because it's not as if the friend or his wife were unaware that a foreign country would have a different culture, cuisine or language. Almost any major company hiring foreign employees has contracted cross-cultural specialists to help employees and families prepare to acclimate to going abroad, or foreign hires coming to their location. If he really didn't discuss the change or listen to his wife about the change, that's on him, and it should not be brought up. If he did, and she agreed and now is complaining about that, it also should not be brought up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say there is no real need to convince the employer of anything. The employer cannot *make* him travel there and work for them. What he needs to do is *tell* them he will not be able to join.

There's no need to be harsh in the communication either. And given that this was not something anyone could have expected to happen, he won't be considered stupid for it, either.

But what he will need to do, if he is certain about not being able to go out, is be direct, and be honest with the employer.

A message explaining the situation, along with an apology for the circumstances could look like this:

> Due to unforeseen family problems, I have decided that I am unable to emigrate at this time. This means I will be unable to join the company. I am very sorry for this turn of events as I was very much looking forward to the job.

There's not much the company can do at that point; they will have to cut their losses and start looking for a new person. Which is also he'd want to send this out sooner rather than later; dragging it on makes it look bad.

As for the next time your friend looks for a job, he should probably spend more time thinking over the ramifications of moving abroad. It's a big change, for him *and* his family and everyone should have their expectations aligned on what it's going to mean. Including making sure everyone moving will fit into the local culture and is willing to leave their local friends and family behind.

(Since this situation also involves visas, make sure to check those as well. I don't *think* there's a big problem with not making use of them, but I can't be sure. You might want to check with the embassy about that. You might have to officially cancel it or something.)

Comment: Since few people discussed about legal actions here, I am interested in knowing what could happen and how it would affect his future employment?

Comment: @johndoe that is more of a question for a lawyer I think, but you can try and ask it as a separate question. (I'm a bad judge of what'll be closed as legal advice and what can be answered..)

Answer (score 1):

> How should he convince employer that he cannot join without being
>   harsh or looking stupid?

Repay their investment might help, but realistically his best option is just to be blunt. These things happen, but it's very unprofessional and says little good about his wife in the employers eyes.

However they're thousands of miles away so probably can't hurt him except perhaps legal action of some sort if it's warranted.

One other option is to tell his wife to support his career rather than drag him down. It sounds harsh, but she is a problem here that could be addressed. Many expats wives in my country detest the place, but are here in support of their husbands. Some husbands as well who's wives work here.

Comment: What kind of legal action can be taken?

Comment: What if he ask them if he could work remotely?

Comment: And at last what if it happened after month of joining? and could have given a notice period of a week? that could have been a better situation?

Comment: Why should the woman support the man's career, rather than the man supporting the woman's happiness?

Comment: @Erik often families make sacrifices and compromises for the benefit of each other and children. I'd be happy just lazing around all day, but I get up and work hard to build a better future for my family and I'd be nowhere near where I am without the support of my wife. Just as I support her in many things I don't really care about.

Comment: I know that, you just make it sound perfectly normal and natural for the woman to sacrifice her happiness for the career of her husband. You'd think this would be a discussion about priorities as a family, not a "tell her she's holding him down".

Comment: @Erik that sounds better I guess, but I don't mince words with my wife, coming straight out bluntly is more my style, and that's pretty much how I'd phrase it, although I might interpose a pillow between us at the time for protection. And it is normal and natural for both men and women to make sacrifices for their spouses.... in my culture anyway.

Comment: I'm also quite blunt, but this phrasing to me sounds less like being blunt with someone and more just like expecting the world to revolve around your wishes and your career. Which might be one common way to run a relationship, but still not something I'd like to see in a good answer.

Comment: @Erik Feel free to downvote, it's just one of several possible resolutions, other answers might be more to your taste. I tend to go for direct resolutions by addressing the core problems, but there are other strategies which suit other temperaments better.

Comment: @Kilisi you are mixing two things, we all the know that a job offer is not the end of the world, she should sacrifice if it was the only option, in my opinion I would prefer to make my wife happy instead of an employer in far away country who would not think twice before firing me.

Comment: "Repay their investment" - Do you mean the friend should offer to pay something to the company?

Comment: @Brandin if possible yes, I have had to cancel overseas work because of my children. The cause was not the overseas company, they acted in good faith, but me putting my family before my work. A positive gesture of good will is to reimburse some of their loss and bear it myself. I probably didn't need to do this, but my policy is if it's my fault, I'll bear the loss, this has stood me in good stead over the years in terms of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand how this situation unfolded on either side.

The "friend" seems to have not considered even in the slightest the risks of agreeing to this position *without ever even visiting the country* - not only in terms of his wife's wishes, but even in terms of his own.

I don't understand how the wife arrived at this determination that she didn't want to live in Berlin if she has never even been there herself.  It's very possible she has been telling him all along that she didn't want to leave her current home, as well.  We only ever get one side of the story on these points, and in this case it's third hand no less.  Honestly it sounds rather like a convenient excuse to blame everything on the wife, here.

But mostly, I *really* do not understand why a company would invest so much time and money in a candidate who clearly has not taken the steps necessary to make an *informed* decision about moving to a new country and culture to accept the position.  That is simply stunning and IMO the employer is just as naive and culpable as the employee.

Anyway there is nothing to do but simply tell them he is backing out of the deal.  No he will not look good.  No the employer will not admit any partial responsibility for not vetting him better.  And no, he doesn't need to "get a better wife" - he needs to grow up and work these things out with all the people who would be (seriously!) affected by his choices *before* accepting job offers in the future.

ETA:  regarding what recourse the company may have against him, he needs to read his employment contract carefully to determine what he has agreed to.  In German companies, the notice period is normally two weeks (on both sides) during the probation period (which usually lasts 6 months), but of course it depends on the contract he signed.

Comment: They reached Germany, stayed couple of days, went office for signing the contract, in the evening she got sick. They got worried and decided to return back maybe she had some prior issues I don't know.

Comment: Based on your edit/update it sounds like she is very sick indeed.  This is a completely different angle, and I can assure you, even after living in Germany for more than 6 years I still get nervous when faced with thoughts of a major health problem. The healthcare here is excellent - that's not the issue - but it is precisely when you are most vulnerable that the language/culture differences hit home the most.  What a terrible turn this took for them!  I think simply telling the employer "sorry but she is gravely ill and we just can't do this now" would be more than understood.